# context_processors.py: files path?

Tags: python, django

I have a context_processors.py files in one of my app that I declared in my settings.py and it works.
but, as context_processors.py files's data are common to all the project, I would like to declare it at the root of my project but files is not recognized...

current project's architecture

```
- myproject
  - myproject
  - myapp
    - context_processors.py
```

declared as follow in settings.py :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'registration/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'myapp.context_processors.data_context_processor',    <********************
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

expected project's architecture

```
- myproject
  - myproject
    - context_processors.py
  - myapp
```

How should I declare my context_processors.py files in settings.py?
I try with os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'context_processors.data_context_processor') but it does not works...

Comment: Why use `my app` in your when talking about your project's architecture when in your `settings.py` your app is named `parameters`

Comment: sorry, I have corrected

Comment: is my assumption correct that your `myproject/` folder contains `settings.py` and  that the `myproject/` and `myapp/` folders are in the same project folder?

Comment: I have corrected architecture to be more precise

Comment: got it. The answer I provided should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Use the python module/package dot notation

```
'context_processors': [
    'myproject.context_processors.data_context_processor',    
    ...
]
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#packages

Comment: And you don't need to reference the project's root as package - actually, it shouldn't even work, since your project root should NOT be a python package, else you might end up with [double imports](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Consider the fact that the OP is not a Python/Django pro and the way he calls things doesn't necessarily map 1:1 to the correct nomenclature. One could easily interpret `myproject/` in his question as the Django project's python package. The actual project root could be `project_root` with directories `project_root/myproject/` and `project_root/myapp/`.

Comment: re-reading the OP, you are absolutely correct sir - 'my_project' is the project folder, not the project's root. i do apologize, and go get me another coffee ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, when a django setting is used to reference a software component (module, class or callable), what is expected is not a filesystem path but a python qualified path (cf the dot notation, similar to how you'd reference an object's attributes or methods). This will then be dynamically imported, using the same resolution rules as with any Python module (you may want to read about this in the Python doc).

Since the project's root path is always supposed to be first in your `sys.path` (the list of directories python searches for modules and packages), if you want to reference a module or package which is at your project root's top-level, you just directly use the module or package name - just like you did in your settings `INSTALLED_APPS` to reference your app. In your case, `my_project` seems to be the 'project folder' (the one containing your settings, root url conf etc), which is technically a package at  your project's root top-level, so the expected python qualified name is `"my_project.context_processors.data_context_processor"`.